# Character encoding in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, character-encoding

I have some German content which contains an umlaut (ü). This content is being built into an XML file.  I then have a flash file which uses the xml to build a coverflow.  My problem is that the 'ü' character is not being displayed in the coverflow.  I've made sure the xml is encoded correctly, as you can see from the snippet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<artworkinfo>
        <albuminfo>
             <artLocation>../../../../../../../../Trading-und-Grunes-Buch_Green-Book.png</artLocation>
             <albumName>Trading und Grünes Buch (Green Book)</albumName>
             <albumLink>http://www.example.com/trading-und-grunes-buch-green-book.html</albumLink>
             <albumDesc>Dieses Video zeigt...</albumDesc>
        </albuminfo>
</artworkinfo>
```

As you can see, the umlaut is in the albumName element, but when that text displays it simply misses out the 'ü'.  I've added a bunch of encoding groups to the text element in the coverflow file, as well as specifically adding the 'ü' in the 'Include these characters' element.  I'm stuck for how to get this to display.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the font you've selected doesn't have an umlaut.. What happens if you copy and paste one into the text field and publish, does it display?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CDATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <artworkinfo>
            <albuminfo>
                 <artLocation>../../../../../../../../Trading-und-Grunes-Buch_Green-Book.png</artLocation>
                 <albumName><![CDATA[Trading und Grünes Buch (Green Book)]]></albumName>
                 <albumLink>http://www.example.com/trading-und-grunes-buch-green-book.html</albumLink>
                 <albumDesc>Dieses Video zeigt...</albumDesc>
            </albuminfo>
    </artworkinfo>
```

Rob

Comment: Just tried and it still didn't display.  I put the CDATA around the albumName (but inside the albumName element) and also tried it immediately inside the artworkinfo element.

Comment: If you trace the xml contents in AS and you see the character then it will be your font. Probably it doesn't embed this character.

Comment: +1 to heartcode, although technically I think there could be some other possibilities, such as weirdness with TLF textfields, if you're using them. But probably it's the font or the font embed settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an encode method.
for e.g. in classic asp use: Server.HTMLEncode("ü")

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm no longer in a position to try this out :(

Answer (score 0):

1. get a list of all the special chars you need
2. make a string that contains all these characters (hardcoded)
3. call a function that accesses these strings

That way Flash will do font-embedding on all the dodgy characters you need, and they will render OK.

Worked for me anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm no longer in a position to try this out :(. Hopefully this will help someone else though